# USB stick backup/restore tool for Mac, Windows and Linux

Tags: backup, usb-flash-drive, restore

Is there a tool capable to run on Mac, Windows and Linux, that could back up a USB stick?

I frecuently clean-install all tree OSes, even in netbooks with no DVD drive

As it turns out I find myself frecuently switching OSes, to restore USB bootable OS installers into my USB stick, so it would be useful to have handy such piece of sowtware

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a 'universal tool', learn to use [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) - Its native on linux and OS X and there's a [port for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)

There's gui tools as well - [ubuntu image writer](https://launchpad.net/usb-imagewriter) on linux and [image writer on window](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer)s

Comment: Well, dd could be exactly what I am looking for, I'll give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [G4L](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/) to backup a USB drive, or any partition or hard drive. You can use it to restore the created images to another type of drive if you wish. It is a bootable tool so install it on a USB drive and you can keep the images you backup on the same drive.

To install it you'll need for example [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which is in itself an excellent tool copy an OS installer to a USB drive.

Comment: G4L looks, very powerful, even overwhelming, I'm sure I could need it any time... thanks